# Can somebody use my service since another server? Angular 9

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular9

I'm learning angular and have question about security. I'm using angular 9.

Can somebody use my service since another server?

I say this because I worry other person use service url to access my data base.

For example:
This is my controller in asp.net

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Producto/listarProductos")]
    public IEnumerable<ProductoCLS> listarProductos()
    {
        using (BDRestauranteContext bd=new BDRestauranteContext())
        {
            List<ProductoCLS> lista = (from producto in bd.Producto
                                       join categoria in bd.Categoria
                                       on producto.Iidcategoria equals
                                       categoria.Iidcategoria
                                       where producto.Bhabilitado == 1
                                       select new ProductoCLS
                                       {
                                           idproducto = producto.Iidproducto,
                                           nombre = producto.Nombre,
                                           precio =(Decimal)producto.Precio,
                                           stock =(int) producto.Stock,
                                           nombreCategoria = categoria.Nombre 
                                       }).ToList();

            return lista;

        }
    }
```

This is my service in angular:

```
    public getProducto() {
    return this.http.get(this.urlBase + 'api/Producto/listarProductos');
  }
```

Comment: If you do not have any authorization in place on the backend-side you shouldn't worry about somebody using your angular-code, but rather directly talking to the API with any language whatsoever :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add **authorization** logic to both your client and server side.

From Angular side
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/09/07/angular-6-basic-http-authentication-tutorial-example

From Dot Net Core side
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/09/08/aspnet-core-21-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Once you login - you will get an `'authentication-token'`. All your subsequent HTTP requests will have an 'Authorization' header and in the Server side - you need to configure it so that it only entertain those http requests which have the authorization headers.

You can have on plethora of different authentication methods like Azure AD authentication, Facebook, Google, github etc.